# Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, udpclient

I'm new to Python and while creating a client-server UDP ping server program in Python I encountered this severe error. It says:

```
TpyeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

The error is present in the UDPClient.py file, which is:

```
from socket import *
from datetime import *
from time import *

pings = 10
i =0 
server = '127.0.0.1'
servPort = 5369
clientSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
data = 'ping'
databin = bytes(data, 'UTF-8')
while i<pings:
    print("Print number: ",i)
    i += 1
    before = datetime.now()
    clientSock.sendto(databin, (server, servPort) )
    clientSock.settimeout(1)

    try:
       clientMsgm server = cliendSock.recvfrom(1024)
       after = datetime.now()
       diff = before - after
       if(i==10):
            print("Ping", i)

   except timeout:
       print("Ping",i," Request timed out!!!")


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\...\UDPClient.py", line 18, in <module>
clientSock.sendto(databin,server, servPort ) # Send what (i.e.'ping') and to whom and where
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Did you miss a 't' when you assigned `databin`?

Comment: please post the complete traceback, also which python version are you using?

Comment: I guess the error must be before `byes`

Comment: Please always copy and paste transcripts rather than typing them out.  The typo in `TpyeError` makes it hard to know if the typo in `byes` is meaningful or not.

Comment: @bgbg The python version I'm using is 3.4.1

Comment: The server file is present at: http://ideone.com/sjxNkL

Comment: You've fixed the address to be a tuple, but the traceback at the bottom is from a run before that fix

Comment: The line number in the exception doesn't match your sample code either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by trying to combine `str` and `tuple` in an unsupported way

eg:

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "foo" + ("bar",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

I don't think the code sample you included is doing this though

Comment: What should I do? cause uptil 4 pings it works fine, but then it shows me the error!